# How to disable video capture in UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, camera

I'm working on an app that allows image capture, but not video capture, but I can't figure out how to remove the photo/video toggle from a UIImagePickerView. This is the code I'm working with, taken from Apple's documentation:

```
UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

// Displays a control that allows the user to choose picture or
// movie capture, if both are available:
cameraUI.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

// Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
// trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;

cameraUI.delegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:cameraUI animated:YES];
```

I'd like to keep all the camera controls EXCEPT the photo/video switch. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just have to set the mediaType property of UIImagePickerController to only contain images, the one you are using there is used to assign all available media types..you can read about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html), if you arent sure what the types are you can always output them to console and then just set that array with the appropriate one (to allow only pictures)

Comment: Ah, ok. I read through the docs and like you said I set the mediaType to this which seems to work: cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil] autorelease];

Comment: Dont forget `#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>`

Answer (score 31):

Or remove this line:

```
cameraUI.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
```

The default value for cameraUI.mediaTypes is "kUTTypeImage". See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html).

Comment: Dont forget `#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>`

Comment: This is indeed the answer that should have been accepted.

Comment: But kUTTypeImage is unavailable now

Comment: @Gank to use kUTTypeImage you need this: `picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]`. Also you must import `MobileCoreServices`. Answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32407457/144088

Comment: Best answer ...thanks I was stucked for around 3 hours and it was just a line of code....God Bless you