# how to capture camera with UIImagePickerController in swift?

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying use `UIImagePickerController` in swift but isn't work...

my ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var imag : UIView = nil
@IBAction func capture(sender : UIButton) {
    println("Button capture")
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)
    {
        var imag = UIImagePickerController()
        imag.delegate = self
        imag.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
       imag.mediaTypes = kUTTypeImage
        imag.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(imag, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
   }   
}
```

I have errors in following line of code

```
imag.delegate = self 
(Type'ViewControlles does confoorm to protocol 'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate')
imagePicker.mediaTypes = kUTTypeImage   
(use of unresolved identifier kUTTypeImage)
```

I have read that `kUTTypeImage` cant use in swift.but don't know, i am using bad this functions. Any help?

Thanks!!

Comment: I found this: http://beefdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/use-of-undeclared-identifier.html 


Which basically states you need to link MobileCoreServices.framework to your binary, then import as a framework in the class you are using. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 84):

You should also import MobileCoreServices in the controller:

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

and then put the type inside square brackets like this:

```
image.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage]
```

**Swift 2.0 and Higher**

```
image.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
```

Comment: Thank you !  I just spent an hour trying to understand that "unresolved reference" compilation error ... !!

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get this working using a bridging header with `#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>` (to anyone else reading this: DON'T bother trying that)

Comment: Note that kUTTypeImage is a CFString and mediaTypes is expect a string. For this you will want `imag.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]`

Answer (score 43):

### Swift 2.0

In Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7), you need to explicitly cast `kUTTypeImage` (a `CFString`) to `String`:

```
picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
```

And you still need to import Mobile Core Services for this symbol to be defined:

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

That said, the default value of `mediaTypes` is `[kUTTypeImage]` anyway, so you don't need to set it if that's what you want.

Comment: Isn't explicitly allowing only images a good practice in case the default value changes in the future?

Answer (score 24):

also you should add `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to the protocols list of the `ViewController`
and one of the optional delegate functions (if you a planing to get a picture)

This is the working code for your issue:

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
        println("i've got an image");
    }

    @IBAction func capture(sender : UIButton) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){
            println("Button capture")

            var imag = UIImagePickerController()
            imag.delegate = self
            imag.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
            imag.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage]
            imag.allowsEditing = false

            self.presentViewController(imag, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Roman, can you please confirm this works for you with Beta3?  I'm having trouble with the kUTTypeImage reference. thx

Comment: The delegate is different in beta 3 now. How to get UIImage in beta 3?

Comment: This is what I did:
if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {       }

Comment: In Beta5, imag.mediaTypes=[kUTTypeImage] would cause error. Change it to imagePicker.mediaTypes = NSArray(object: kUTTypeImage), and it works fine.

Comment: You can find a modified version of this code which works in Beta 6 here: http://pastebin.com/5RxLDw0f

Comment: @ohyes you're right. Even in the Xcode 6.0.1 you need to type mediaTypes = NSArray(object: kUTTypeImage). Setting it as a normal swift array causes a crash.

Comment: You also have to add MobileCoreServices  to Link Binaries with Libraries

Answer (score 7):

From Your Piece of code its very clear that you are making mistakes at two place one is setting `delegate` and second is setting Media type `imag.mediaTypes = kUTTypeImage`

First One:If you look into the `delegate` definition of `UIImagePickerController` it requires to confirm two protocol `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` so you have to adopt these two protocols in your `viewcontroller` class like as

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate,    UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
```

second error:If you look into the definition part of `mediaTypes` it clearly requires array of media types to passed so do like this

```
imag.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage]
```

Apart from this, I have written a very descent class for the same task

It is easy to understand and integrate.

[Here you go](https://github.com/kamarshad/MediaPicker)

```
//Declare property 
var imagePicker:ImageVideoPicker?

//Call below line of code properly, it will return an image

self.imagePicker = ImageVideoPicker(frame: self.view.frame, superVC: self) { (capturedImage) -> Void in
        if let captureImage = capturedImage{
        //you did it.....

        }

    }
```

Comment: Please can you give reason before down casting my answer.Please i would be very glad to know

Comment: I don't know why people are in so Hurry even they don't try to think,we are here to help each other.I request you all whenever you gonna make any down voting, Please do mention the reason in a comment.It will help me and others too

Comment: I think you should make it clearer that ImageVideoPicker is your own class. I didn't downvote you but I did waste time checking to see if ImageVideoPicker was a new swift-only class or something.

Comment: You asked for an explanation and now you're belittling me for providing one. Classy.

Answer (score 2):

You have to conform to the delegate like this

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
```

Per documentation, by default the media types is set to image so you can go ahead and delete that line since you are only setting it to image.

Do not forget to implement the protocol methods which are outlined in the documentation:
[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController%3adidFinishPickingMediaWithInfo%3a)

Comment: but nnot in line imag.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String], exist kUTTypeImage in Swift?? or there are other form to use camera?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

@IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func takeImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    ImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**swift 1.2 syntax:**

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]



    }
```