# How to get UIImage from UIImagePickerControllerDelegate in Swift beta 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I found some related posts:

[UIImagePickerControllerDelegate to Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262990/how-to-capture-camera-with-uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift)

[how to capture camera with UIImagePickerController in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262990/how-to-capture-camera-with-uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift)

But none of them works for beta 3 because the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate changed:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
```

My question is how to get UIImage object from info Array? Thanks

Comment: I know info is a dictionary. But still don't know how to get UIImage like what I did in Objective-c.

Comment: Why down vote my question, moron?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a dictionary, index it with `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`

```
let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
```

Comment: I just found this too after try and error. Thanks.
        
let img : UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

Comment: Edited to include the casting. You shouldn't need `as?` since it will always be an image.

Comment: Yes. That's right. Actually my real code is inside a if statement so that as? is included.